# Python - Loop through folders, each folder create a database in mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I would like to create a database in mysql for each folder name from a path.

```
import MySQLdb
db1 = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="password")
cursor = db1.cursor()
#sql = 'CREATE DATABASE chom'
#cursor.execute(sql)

# "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75570581/python-loop-through-folders-each-folder-create-a-database-in-mysql"
import os
rootdir = 'D:\StackExchange\stackexchangeparser\Output'
for rootdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
  for subdir in dirs:
    
    sql = 'CREATE DATABASE ' + subdir
    cursor.execute(sql)
    print(sql)
```

Please help if you can.

Comment: Why do you negate `isdir` check? You want it to be a directory, don't you? Also, when describing a problem, "no luck" is not a proper description of what's not working. Be much more precise.

Comment: You can also just iterate through `dir`. You don't need to use `range` and numeric indexes

Comment: I recommend not using `path` as variable name, as although it might not do anything in this case, it might cause clashes when dealing with system-related things.

Comment: this would pnöy work, when you have eliminated all characters and words that mysql doesn't loke. but bette would be to use backticks around the folder name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import mysql.connector as mysql_connector

db1 = mysql_connector.connect(
    host="localhost", user="root", passwd="password")
print(db1.is_connected)
cursor1 = db1.cursor()


def getDirectries(path):
    dir = os.listdir(path)
    dir_list = []
    for value in dir:
        if os.path.isdir(path+"/"+value):
            dir_list.append(value)
    return dir_list


path = "."
dir = getDirectries(path)
print(dir)

for i in dir:
    sql = 'CREATE DATABASE '+i
    try:
        cursor1.execute(sql)
    except:
        print("error")

cursor1.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This is what I was looking to solve however I still get error when it tries to create the databases:" <bound method CMySQLConnection.is_connected of <mysql.connector.connection_cext.CMySQLConnection object at 0x0000021B7F1E8CD0>>
['coffee.meta.stackexchange.com', 'Stackoverflow.com-Posts']
error
error
"

Comment: I think it's error in the name of database. there shouldn't be spaces or any full stop in name. It is suggested the name of database should contain alphaphets and underscore only.  you can replace the dots while creating database.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).